# How to draw sectional plot for a 3D parameter equation?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, implicit

How to draw sectional plot for a 3D parameter equation?

Firstly, the MMA code is given as

```
A = -2/3000;
F = (7 Sinh[\[Xi] - 0.3 t])/(30 Cosh[\[Xi] - 0.3 t]) - (
   23 Sinh[\[Xi] - 0.3 t])/(60 (Cosh[\[Xi] - 0.3 t])^3) + (
   7 Sinh[\[Xi] - 0.1 t])/(15 Cosh[\[Xi] - 0.1 t]) - (
   23 Sinh[\[Xi] - 0.1 t])/(30 (Cosh[\[Xi] - 0.1 t])^3) - (
   7 Sinh[\[Xi] + 0.1 t])/(15 Cosh[\[Xi] + 0.1 t]) + (
   23 Sinh[\[Xi] + 0.1 t])/(30 (Cosh[\[Xi] + 0.1 t])^3) + 10;
FX = 0.3 (Sech[\[Xi] - 0.3 t])^2 + 0.5 (Sech[\[Xi] - 0.1 t])^2 - 
   0.8 (Sech[\[Xi] + 0.1 t])^2;
G = (7 Sinh[\[Eta]])/(30 Cosh[\[Eta]]) - (23 Sinh[\[Eta]])/(
   60 (Cosh[\[Eta]])^3);
GY = 0.3 (Sech[\[Eta]])^2;
func[\[Xi]_, \[Eta]_, t_] = (-3 FX*GY)/(2 A (F + G)^2);
With[{t = -25}, 
 With[{X = \[Xi] - 0.5 Tanh[\[Xi] - 0.3 t] - Tanh[\[Xi] - 0.1 t] - 
     1.5 Tanh[\[Xi] + 0.1 t], Y = \[Eta] - 1.15 Tanh[\[Eta]]}, 
  ParametricPlot3D[{X, Y, func[\[Xi], \[Eta], t]}, {\[Xi], 
    4, -10}, {\[Eta], 3, -3}, PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> None, 
   PlotPoints -> 100, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
   AxesLabel -> {Style[x, {15}], Style[y, {15}]}]]]
```

and it comes

[image]

Here, I would like to draw a 2D sectional plot for this 3D graphic at y=0, such as

[image]

To achieve this goal, my code is

```
Y = 0;
With[{t = -25}, 
 With[{X = \[Xi] - 0.5 Tanh[\[Xi] - 0.3 t] - Tanh[\[Xi] - 0.1 t] - 
     1.5 Tanh[\[Xi] + 0.1 t]}, 
  ParametricPlot[{X, func[\[Xi], \[Eta], t]}, {\[Xi], 
    5, -10}, {\[Eta], 3, -3}, PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> None, 
   PlotPoints -> 100, AxesLabel -> {Style[x, {15}], Style[y, {15}]}]]]
```

and it comes

[image]

How can I get the second picture(line sectional plot)?

cross-post: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2444906?p_p_auth=9qba31rV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `η = 0`

```
With[{t = -25}, 
 With[{X = ξ - 0.5 Tanh[ξ - 0.3 t] - Tanh[ξ - 0.1 t] - 
     1.5 Tanh[ξ + 0.1 t], η = 0}, 
  ParametricPlot[{X, func[ξ, η, t]}, {ξ, 5, -10}, 
   PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> None, 
   PlotPoints -> 100, 
   AxesLabel -> {Style[x, 15], Style[y, 15]},
   AspectRatio -> 1]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Set

```
MeshFunctions -> {#4 &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> Thick, 
   PlotStyle -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None
```

That is

```
Y = 0;
With[{t = -25}, 
 With[{X = ξ - 0.5 Tanh[ξ - 0.3 t] - Tanh[ξ - 0.1 t] - 
     1.5 Tanh[ξ + 0.1 t]}, 
  ParametricPlot[{X, func[ξ, η, t]}, {ξ, 
    5, -10}, {η, 3, -3}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 100, 
   MeshFunctions -> {#4 &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> Thick, 
   PlotStyle -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
   AxesLabel -> {Style[x, {15}], Style[y, {15}]}]]]
```

[image]